# How do I compare my CSV to my config as I am iterating through each one?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name-here')

def verify_unique_col():
    with open(r'unique_columns.json', 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='decrypted/'):
        if my_bucket_object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]
            for table in config['Unique_Column_Combination']['Table_Name']:
                unique_col_comb = config['Unique_Column_Combination']['Table_Name'][f'{table}']
                df = pd.read_csv(f's3://path/to/{filename}', sep='|')
                df_unique = df.set_index(unique_col_comb.split(", ")).index.is_unique       
                print(df_unique)

verify_unique_col()
```

I am trying to iterate through each CSV file in my bucket and read each one in `df = pd.read_csv(f's3://path/to/{filename}', sep='|')` and after reading one, I want to determine if the data for the columns in that CSV are unique. I listed the columns that are supposed to be unique in my config file here:

```
{
    "Unique_Column_Combination":
    {
        "Table_Name":{
            "TABLE_1": "CLIENT, ADDRNUMBER, PERSNUMBER, CONSNUMBER, LAST_LOAD_DT",
            "TABLE_2": "CLIENT, ADDRNUMBER, CONSNUMBER, LAST_LOAD_DT",
            "TABLE_3": "CLIENT, ADDRNUMBER, DATE_FROM, NATION, LAST_LOAD_DT",
            "TABLE_4": "COMM_TYPE, CONSNUMBER, COMM_USAGE, VALID_TO, LOAD_DT",
        }
    }
}
```

So I want my code to read the csv `TABLE_1.csv` then check if the columns above in `TABLE_1` for that table are unique, then move onto `TABLE_2.csv` and check if the columns above in `TABLE_2` are unique and so on...the way my code is right now, is that it iterates through each `Table_Name` in my config just fine, but it is only reading the first CSV in my s3 bucket and comparing the first CSV to all of my tables listed in my config. I want to do a comparison from TABLE_1.csv to TABLE_1 and TABLE_2.csv to TABLE_2 and so on...is that possible? In theory I thought it was but it appears to be too muddled...

Comment: So, you just want to determine if there are any duplicated rows in a single file?  That can be done with `pd.drop_duplicates` and seeing if the line count changes.  Or are you trying to check ACROSS files?

Comment: i just want to find a way to iterate the process i already have through each csv file i am reading

Comment: Your function already iterates through the bucket, doesn't it?  I'm confused about what isn't working.

Comment: When I execute the code, the results currently are:

`TABLE_1.csv
True
TABLE_1.csv
True`

But I want the output to be:

`TABLE_1.csv
True
TABLE_2.csv
True`

Comment: basically it's iterating through the bucket but it's only comparing the first csv file it's grabbing to my entire JSON config instead of comparing TABLE_1.csv to TABLE_1 and TABLE_2.csv to TABLE_2

Comment: So, are you saying, if the filename is "TABLE_1.csv" then you want to use the "TABLE_1" row in your config?  Because I don't see you extracting the table name from the file name.

Comment: yes. i am extracting the filename here: `filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]` do i need to extract the table name from this? i don't see why, i just want to read the first CSV which is `filename` and it iterates through each file in my bucket

Comment: But "TABLE_1.csv" is not the same as "TABLE_1".  Is that just a cut-and-paste problem where you shrouded the actual data?

Comment: yeah TABLE_1.csv is the csv file that is being compared to TABLE_1 which is the list of columns. the code works and compares both variables correctly, but when i loop it through my for loop, TABLE_1.csv is being compared against the remaining tables in the config

Comment: Yes, because you asked it to do that with the `for` loop.  You should DELETE the `for` loop and do `table = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]`, which will remove the extension.

Comment: so am i supposed to keep `filename = my_bucket_object.key.split('/')[-1]` and `table = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]` because I did and I got the same output as before. `True
TABLE_1.csv
True
TABLE_1.csv`

Comment: Yes.  Just replace the `for` statement with that line, and un-indent the four lines in the loop.

Comment: ok im still confused on how this should look...if i delete the forloop then it keeps saying filename referenced before assignment or table referenced before assignment.

Comment: nevermind i was looking at the wrong forloop....it works now thank you for your help!